# Azure Cognitive Services - System assigned identity in Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-cognitive-services, infrastructure-as-code

How can you create an Azure Cognitive Services Account with System assigned identity in Terraform?

I have tried the following but got an error: **Blocks of type "identity" are not expected here.**

```
resource "azurerm_cognitive_account" "cgsrv" {
  # Conditionally based on feature flag
  count                     = var.to_provision == true ? 1 : 0
  name                      = lower(replace("${var.name_params.prefix}-cgnsrv-${var.name_params.use_case_name}", "-", ""))
  location                  = var.location
  resource_group_name       = var.resourcegroup_name
  kind                      = "CognitiveServices"
  sku_name                  = "S0"

  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, the terraform documentation does not mention this ability at the moment (see [here](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/cognitive_account))

The provider is open-sourced, you can find the source [here](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/blob/master/azurerm/internal/services/cognitive/cognitive_account_resource.go) and it looks like there is a pull request regarding this specific field: https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/pull/12469

Comment: thanks! I guess for the time being I will create a post-deployment Powershell script.